# Avoid synchronizing required fields with marketing cloud connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, fields, marketing-cloud-connect, sync

Is there away to avoid synchronizing required fields with Marketing Cloud Connect?
We have our own custom fields to manage opt-outs, so to avoid confusion for the end users we would like to avoid synchronizing the HasOptedOutOfEmail field on the contact. But it is listed as a required field? Is there anyway to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. When a field is set to not visible it is no longer a part of the required fields.